# Download previous firefox version for Android

Tags: firefox, android

Are there any trusted sites where I can download previous Firefox versions? The reason I want to switch because some of my addons aren't supported on it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please check the On Topic page for other SE websites before redirecting people there. This question seems to be off topic for Android SE too: "Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here: [...] - Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it"

Comment: For a computer, I have used Filehippo.  Don't know if that works for Android too.  You might want to post your question at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=38

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a web directory of all previous versions of Mozilla Firefox for Android : [Index of /pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/).

Comment: It's not a system app, so updates cannot be uninstalled in this fashion. The latter should work, but the OP will need to remove the app first, which will delete all data associated with it.